# Difference between rospy.spin and rospy.sleep

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi There!
Whats the difference between rospy.spin nad rospy.sleep? Does rospy.rate affect rospy.spin?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332192/difference-between-rospy.spin-and-rospy.sleep/) by [Marseiliais](https://answers.ros.org/users/45338/marseiliais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-09-02

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rospy.spin()` will effectively go into an infinite loop until it receives a shutdown signal (e.g. `ctrl-c`). During that loop it will process any events that occur, such as data received on a topic or a timer triggering, when they occur but otherwise it will sleep. You should use `spin()` when your node doesn't do anything outside of its callbacks.

`rospy.sleep()` will do the same as `rospy.spin()` but [only for the length of time you specify](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Time#Sleeping_and_Rates). It is used when your node has to do some kind of regular processing in addition to responding to topic events, timer events, etc. For example, a node controlling a motor will need to do some processing at regular intervals to set the motor's desired speed.

(Technically, what both are doing is sleeping your main thread and allowing other, internal threads to do their work.)

---

Originally posted by [Geoff](https://answers.ros.org/users/20134/geoff/) with karma: 4203 on 2019-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shivam](https://answers.ros.org/users/84595/shivam/) on 2021-10-04**:
I didn't understand the part  "It is used when your node has to do some kind of regular processing in addition to responding to topic events, timer events, etc."  ;(
Can you please explain in codes what this would mean? If I have two functions in a node. One does image processing and the other one controls the robot. When I use rospy.sleep(20) after each function, It just waits 20 sec to run the loop again. rospy.spin() I used like this-

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
    try:
        talker()
        main(sys.argv)
        rospy.spin()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Here main() has a call to another function in it's code. So my question is does rospy.spin() run this try: block of code again and again?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-02-17**:
@Shivam  Please open a new question, as comment section is NOT meant to ask a new question.